# a summable series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

one question about a series:

Given a summable sequence $a_i$ (i.e. $\sum_{i}a_i=1$)

can we show that there is a constant $b\in (0,1], C>0$ s.t. $\sum_{i:a_i<\epsilon}a_i\le C \epsilon^{b}, \forall \epsilon>0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence which has the term $2^{-n}$ repeated $\left\lfloor \frac{2^n}{n^2}\right\rfloor$ times, for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ in turn.  Its sum converges (to a value below $\frac{\pi^2}6$).  However if we consider the terms of size less than $\frac1{2^n-1}$, their sum is greater than $\frac1{n^2}-2^{-n}$.

For any $b,C>0$, we have $\frac1{n^2}-2^{-n}$ asymptotically $\frac1{n^2}$, whilst $C\left(\frac1{2^n-1}\right)^b$ is asymptotically $(2^b)^{-n}$. Thus for sufficiently large $n$ we have: $$
\frac1{n^2}-2^{-n}> C\left(\frac1{2^n-1}\right)^b.$$ Thus the statement fails in this case for any choice of $b,C$, demonstrated by taking $\epsilon=\frac1{2^n-1}$ for some $n$ sufficiently large.